# SQL Server 2012: Weighted Average Calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to calculate the weighted average maturity of some data in my table.

```
SaleEventID  LID(PK)    CurrentUPB         Interest Rate    RemainingMonths
1            1          $100,000.00         6.100%           11.00
1            2          $67,000.00          6.200%           360.00
1            3          $1,400,000.00       6.300%           240.00
1            4          $500,000.00         7.000%           100.00
2            5          $1,400,000.00       7.100%           240.00
2            6          $500,000.00         7.000%           100.00
```

**So the formula i'm trying to accomplish is (WAM):**
1) Multiply CurrentUPB * RemainingMonths for LID=1
2) Do that for each row that matches WHERE SaleEventID=1
3) SUM the above calculation = `$411,220,000.00` = A
4) SUM all the CurrentUPB WHERE SaleEventID=1 which equals `$2,067,000.00` =B
5) Then Divide A/B = `$198.95` which is my WAM

I need to consider that in my table I will have many Loans and that each will not be attributed the same `SaleEventID` value (Which is not the Primary Key)

My query so far:

```
SELECT l.*, A / B FROM AS WAM
FROM ( SELECT LSX_DC_Loans l
        (SELECT CurrentUPB * RemainingMonths FROM l WHERE LID = 1
         ) AS A
        (SELECT SUM (CurrentUPB) CurrentUPB FROM LSX_DC_Loans
        WHERE SaleEventID = 1
        ) AS B
FROM l
) l
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do steps 2 & 4. Any help, examples highly appreciated.

Comment: What is LoanA ?

Comment: Just Updated the question had miss typed the information in the grid.

Comment: $411,220,000/$3,967,000 =$103.6602  wheres 198.95 come from?

Comment: Sorry @xQbert grabbed that from my excel had 2 extra rows the values were  $411,220,000.00 /  $2,067,000.00  = 198.95 I've updated the question in case someone runs into this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To calculate WAM and WAIR is pretty simple.  Think sumproduct() in Excel

```
Declare @YourTable table (SaleEventID  int,LID int,CurrentUPB money,[Interest Rate] money,RemainingMonths money)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,1,100000.00,6.100, 11.00),
(1,2,67000.00,6.200, 360.00),
(1,3,1400000.00,6.300, 240.00),
(1,4,500000.00,7.000, 100.00),
(2,5,1400000.00,7.100, 240.00),
(2,6,500000.00,7.000,100.00)


Select SaleEventID
      ,UPB  = sum(CurrentUPB)
      ,WAM  = sum(CurrentUPB*RemainingMonths)/sum(CurrentUPB)
      ,WAIR = sum(CurrentUPB*[Interest Rate] )/sum(CurrentUPB)
 From  @YourTable
 Where SaleEventID = @Event
 Group By SaleEventID
```

Returns

```
SaleEventID UPB         WAM         WAIR
1           2067000.00  198.9453    6.4564
2           1900000.00  203.1578    7.0736
```

Comment: Wow. You're a pro.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you John

Comment: @DVT Nope.  Just spent a couple of decades in the Banking Industry  :)

Comment: John, how can I add a WHERE clause to this to pass in a SaleEventID into the query. I'm planning on using this on a website and pulling the SaleEventID from querystring.

Comment: @AlexP See Updated answer

Comment: @JohnCappelletti ah facepalm i was adding it after the GROUP BY. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here is the answer

```
SELECT
    l.*
    , l1.A / l2.B AS WAM
FROM
    LXC_DC_Loans l
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(CurrentUPB * RemainingMonths) AS A FROM LSX_DC_Loans WHERE SaleEventID=l.SaleEventID) l1
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(CurrentUPB) AS B A FROM LSX_DC_Loans WHERE SaleEventID=l.SaleEventID) l2
```