# Calculating daily average transaction balance of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

need to calculate daily average balance of ids. firstdate is when the ID was generated, currentdate is the dates with balance  shown for the IDs.

[image: image1]

I am expecting something like this [image 2](manually calculated) for each IDs. So basically need to calculate numbers of days between the firstdate when the id was generated and the last currentdate and the balance should be filled in the blank (between dates) to accurately calculating the daily average.

[image: image2]

I created the calender table but not sure how I can get the balance for everyday in order to calculate the average.

```
CREATE TABLE #Calendar
(
    [CalendarDate] DATE
)

DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE
SET @StartDate = '20000101' 
SET @EndDate = GETDATE() 

WHILE @StartDate <= @EndDate
      BEGIN
             INSERT INTO #Calendar
             (
                   CalendarDate
             )
             SELECT
                   @StartDate

             SET @StartDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @StartDate)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please don't post images of sample data, post it in a consumable format; preferable DDL and DML statements. I also don't understand the values you are after. How did you get 364 as the average of 300, 400 and 100? I make it 266.66~.

Comment: please explain briefly

Comment: @Larnu  I suspect a day-weighted average

Comment: Side note, using a `WHILE` to create a temporary calendar table will be *terrible* for performance. Use a Tally if you must generate it on the fly.

Comment: If truly a day-weighted average, you need to explain what happens to the last observation.   Balance extended to Current Date ?  End of Month? End of Year ?    Perhaps this will help.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939006/sql-server-2012-weighted-average-calculation/40939142#40939142   The "weight" will be the number of days of the Spot Balance.

Comment: @Lamu if you look at the (for example id 110) date that span to 28 days that means if the balance on 20190614 is 300 then on 20190615 it is 300 till 20190618 and on 20190619 balance is 400 and balance remain 400 each day till 20190710. To calculate daily balance average , sum of balance each day divided by number of days between when Id was generated (firstdate) and last currentdate.

Comment: L a **r n** u @suz_chak , please.

Comment: But you have overlapping days, @suz_chak . YOu have that it was 300, 400 *and* 100 on 20190614. You need to [edit] your question and explain more, while fixing your sampel data.

Comment: @Larnu 6/14 is the origination date.   "Current Date" is the date of the SPOT Balance.   Current Date is the real key here.

Comment: @Lamu, that was ID was generated, its same for all rows of a particular id. currentdate when the balance changes (transactions).

Comment: I've already kindly asked you to spell my alias correctly once, @suz_chak ...

Comment: I get what you are doing (decades in banking), but you haven't explained how you are weighing 7/11

Comment: @Larnu, sorry small screen. apology.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  that doesn't tell us where 364 comes from. *if* we apply that logic we have 5 days @ 300, 22 @ 400 and 768 @ 100 (assuming to the current date (2021-08-17) as there's no further data for that ID). That would make the "average" `((5 * 300) + (22 * 400) + (768 * 100)) / (5 +22 +768)`, which is 109...

Comment: @Larnu That's the problem.  OP has still not explained last observation.  I also assumed Current Date, but this doesn't feel like real-world.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti for simplicity it was calculated manually for last Currentdate balance only not the GETDATE(), but you are right.

Comment: @Larnu its dummy data but real world is similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the last observation is weighted to `getdate()`

There is no need for a calendar table, you can use the window function `lead() over()` to determine the number of days.

**Example**

```
 Select ID
       ,ADB = sum(Balance*Days)/sum(Days)
 From  (
        Select * 
              ,Days =  datediff(Day,CurrentDate,lead(CurrentDate,1,getdate() ) over (partition by ID order by CurrentDate ) ) 
         from YourTable
       ) A
 Group By ID
```

**Results**

```
ID  ADB
110 109.5597
```

**EDIT**

I should add that the window functions can invaluable.  They are well worth your time getting comfortable with them.

Comment: thanks but how would you insert thousands of different IDs and millions of balance rows !! appreciate

Comment: @suz_chak the table variable is just demonstrative.

Comment: @suz_chak See updated answer.  I removed the table variable.

Comment: @suz_chak just change lead(CurrentDate,1,getdate() )  to lead(CurrentDate,1,CurrentDate )   This means the last observed date would have a weight of Zero