# Excel's SUMPRODUCT in SQL across tables without huge joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sumproduct

Wondering what the options are to do Excel's SUMPRODUCT in SQL Server.

I have 3 tables:

1. Transaction list of items being sold
2. Raw materials making up each item
3. Price of raw materials by date

For each item sold (table 1), I want to find the total price of raw materials (table 3) on that sold date, considering the % of raw materials that make up the item. Sample data below.

Table 1: Items sold

| Item | Date | Qty_sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pencil | 5/1/2022 | 1 |
| Pencil | 6/1/2022 | 2 |
| Pencil | 9/1/2022 | 1 |

Table 2: Raw materials making up each item

| Item | Raw_material | pct_of_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Pencil | Wood | 70% |
| Pencil | Rubber | 5% |
| Pencil | Lead | 25% |

Table 3: Raw material prices by date

| Date | Raw_material | Part_unitprice |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5/1/2022 | Wood | 0.20 |
| 6/1/2022 | Wood | 0.21 |
| 9/1/2022 | Wood | 0.21 |
| 5/1/2022 | Rubber | 0.10 |
| 6/1/2022 | Rubber | 0.10 |
| 9/1/2022 | Rubber | 0.12 |
| 5/1/2022 | Lead | 0.50 |
| 6/1/2022 | Lead | 0.55 |
| 9/1/2022 | Lead | 0.50 |

The result I'm looking for is below, at the same level of detail as Table 1.

| Item | Date | Qty_sold | SUMPRODUCT_unitprice |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Pencil | 5/1/2022 | 1 | 0.27 |
| Pencil | 6/1/2022 | 2 | 0.2895 |
| Pencil | 9/1/2022 | 1 | 0.278 |

My approach would be to

1. First join Table 2 (~3k rows) & Table 3 (~72k rows)
2. Join the resulting table with Table 1 (> 2M rows)

I'm conscious of the number of rows that would need to get crunched with these two joins, and I'm wondering if there is a more sophisticated way of doing this.

Comment: I'm getting Factorio vibes...

Comment: Your joins will/should include dates ... I don't see the anticipated problem of huge numbers of rows (this should not not a cartesian join).

Comment: @topsail Even if a Cartesian Product was involved in the query as a conceptual intermediate step, the actual RDBMS will be smarter than that to actually do that. Besides, what _really_ matters re: performance are the indexes on the tables involved.

Comment: SUMPRODUCT in SQL Server is a simple as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939006/sql-server-2012-weighted-average-calculation/40939142#40939142

Comment: Will every sale date be covered by matching raw material price dates, or will there be a need to look up the most recent price to an arbitrary sale date? For example, could there be 8/1/2022 sales that would need to use 6/1/2022 prices?

Comment: Every sale date should be covered by matching raw material price dates

Answer (score 1):

This is an example query where you can calculate the required sumproduct value. Just note that I don't see any reason to worry about "huge numbers of rows" here. This is not a cartesian join.

```
select 
    t1.Item,
    t1.[Date],
    t1.Qty_Sold, sum(t2.pct_of_total * t3.Part_UnitPrice) as SumProduct_UnitPrice
from
    #Table1 t1
    inner join #Table2 t2
    on t2.Item = t1.Item
    inner join #Table3 t3
    on t3.Raw_Material = t2.Raw_Material
    and t3.[Date] = t1.[Date]
group by
    t1.Item, t1.[Date], t1.Qty_Sold;
```

For completeness sake, my test data:

```
drop table if exists #Table1, #Table2, #Table3

create table #Table1 (Item nvarchar(30), [Date] date, Qty_Sold int)
insert into #Table1 values 
    ('Pencil', '20220501', 1),
    ('Pencil', '20220601', 2),
    ('Pencil', '20220901', 1)

create table #Table2 (Item nvarchar(30), Raw_Material nvarchar(30), pct_of_total decimal(5, 2))
insert into #Table2 values
    ('Pencil', 'Wood', .70),
    ('Pencil', 'Rubber', .05),
    ('Pencil', 'Lead', .25)


create table #Table3 ([Date] date, Raw_Material nvarchar(30), Part_UnitPrice decimal(5,2))
insert into #Table3 values
    ('20220501', 'Wood', .20),
    ('20220601', 'Wood', .21),
    ('20220901', 'Wood', .21),
    ('20220501', 'Rubber', .10),
    ('20220601', 'Rubber', .10),
    ('20220901', 'Rubber', .12),
    ('20220501', 'Lead', .50),
    ('20220601', 'Lead', .55),
    ('20220901', 'Lead', .50)
```